# Why is my phone seen as a hotspot, but not my iPad?

Tags: macos, ios, wifi

a picture:

[image]

The phone is in the "Personal Hotspots" category, but the iPad is not.

One notable difference is that the phone is always visible, even with the screen turned off, while the iPad needs to be woken up to be visible.

What is the difference due to?
And, how can I get the iPad to be part of the personal hotspots?

Comment: Does your iPad have a SIM & an LTE/4G/3G etc network connection over that?

Comment: yes, it does; I'm using it as the main hotspot

Comment: Difference can be due to low power mode on iPad. Also, are continuity settings the same on both ? If you manually disconnect iPad, wont it appear in the list ?

Comment: I have handsoff disabled on both. What do you mean by manually disconnect the iPad?